# Why my Oracle 12C is allowing me to a connection creation without passing network security and integrity parameters

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, configuration

My Integrity settings Oracle Net Manager are:
-- Integrity for - Server 
Checksum level - REQUIRED 
Selected Method : SHA1

-- Integrity for- CLIENT 
Checksum level - REQUIRED 
Selected Method : SHA1

-- Encryption for - Server
Encryption Type - REQUIRED
Seed: "encryption seed"
Algorithm - AES256

-- Encryption for - CLIENT
Encryption Type - REQUIRED
Seed: "encryption seed"
Algorithm - AES256

--

Now my test program 1: With security parameters : **Works FINE**

```
    Properties prop = new Properties();

    prop.put("oracle.net.encryption_client", "REJECTED");
    prop.put("oracle.net.encryption_types_client", "AES192");
    prop.put("oracle.net.crypto_checksum_client", "REJECTED");
    prop.put("oracle.net.crypto_checksum_types_client", "SHA1");


    OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
    dataSource.setServerName("192.168.42.191");
    dataSource.setPortNumber(1521);
    dataSource.setDriverType("thin");
    dataSource.setDatabaseName("orcl");
    dataSource.setUser("system");
    dataSource.setPassword("dkpune");
    dataSource.setConnectionProperties(prop);
    m_cOrclConnection = dataSource.getConnection();
```

--
Now my test program 1: Without security parameters: **Works FINE**

Properties prop = new Properties();

```
OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
dataSource.setServerName("192.168.42.191");
dataSource.setPortNumber(1521);
dataSource.setDriverType("thin");
dataSource.setDatabaseName("orcl");
dataSource.setUser("system");
dataSource.setPassword("dkpune");
dataSource.setConnectionProperties(prop);
m_cOrclConnection = dataSource.getConnection();
```

I am not able to understand the difference, why my test stub is returning valid connection instance in both of the cases.

the connection creation in 2nd case should throw an exception. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Please add the settings in sqlnet.ora and what front end language and version you are using to construct the connection

Comment: Your second case will connect but your first case should not connect to database.For thin drivers default encryption and integrity level is `ACCEPTED`.Post sqlnet.ora on server side and client side.